# How to make an HTTP get request with parameters

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, get

Is it possible to pass parameters with an `HTTP` get request? If so, how should I then do it? I have found an `HTTP` post requst ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)). In that example the string `postData` is sent to a webserver. I would like to do the same using *get* instead. Google found this example on `HTTP` get [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307023). However no parameters are sent to the web server.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In a GET request, you pass parameters as part of the query string.

```
string url = "http://somesite.com?var=12345";
```

Comment: If you enter the complete url including the parameters in the adresse bar of iexplore, do I then get the same response as is make a http request get from c#

Comment: Updated. The other answer is more complete anyway.

Answer (score 155):

My preferred way is this. It handles the escaping and parsing for you.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.QueryString.Add("param1", "value1");
webClient.QueryString.Add("param2", "value2");
string result = webClient.DownloadString("http://theurl.com");
```

Answer (score 99):

First `WebClient` is easier to use; GET arguments are specified on the query-string - the only trick is to remember to escape any values:

```
        string address = string.Format(
            "http://foobar/somepage?arg1={0}&arg2={1}",
            Uri.EscapeDataString("escape me"),
            Uri.EscapeDataString("& me !!"));
        string text;
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            text = client.DownloadString(address);
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

The WebRequest object seems like too much work for me. I prefer to use the WebClient control.

To use this function you just need to create two NameValueCollections holding your parameters and request headers.

Consider the following function:

```
    private static string DoGET(string URL,NameValueCollection QueryStringParameters = null, NameValueCollection RequestHeaders = null)
    {
        string ResponseText = null;
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                if (RequestHeaders != null)
                {
                    if (RequestHeaders.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (string header in RequestHeaders.AllKeys)
                            client.Headers.Add(header, RequestHeaders[header]);
                    }
                }
                if (QueryStringParameters != null)
                {
                    if (QueryStringParameters.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (string parm in QueryStringParameters.AllKeys)
                            client.QueryString.Add(parm, QueryStringParameters[parm]);
                    }
                }
                byte[] ResponseBytes = client.DownloadData(URL);
                ResponseText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ResponseBytes);
            }
            catch (WebException exception)
            {
                if (exception.Response != null)
                {
                    var responseStream = exception.Response.GetResponseStream();

                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            Response.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ResponseText;
    }
```

Add your querystring parameters (if required) as a NameValueCollection like so.

```
        NameValueCollection QueryStringParameters = new NameValueCollection();
        QueryStringParameters.Add("id", "123");
        QueryStringParameters.Add("category", "A");
```

Add your http headers (if required) as a NameValueCollection like so.

```
        NameValueCollection RequestHttpHeaders = new NameValueCollection();
        RequestHttpHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic bGF3c2912XBANzg5ITppc2ltCzEF");
```

Answer (score 5):

GET request with multiple params:

> curl --request GET --url
> http://localhost:8080/todos/**?limit=10&offset=2** --header
> 'content-type:application/json'

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass value directly via URL.

If you want to call method
`public static void calling(string name){....}`

then you should call using`HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:****/Report/calling?name=Priya);
webrequest.Method = "GET";
webrequest.ContentType = "application/text";`

Just make sure you are using  `?Object = value` in URL