# Calling class ASP Web Service from C#

Tags: c#, class, asp-classic, biztalk

I have a web service that seems to be written in classic asp as its url looks like this: http://www.example.com/xmlrequest.asp

I have got some java code which is calling this service by appending a URL parameter ?xml="actualxml" .

How can I implement this in C#  by calling the xml as a query string parameter ?

Comment: Are you rebuilding the service or are you moving from java to c# to get the data?  To get it, it would be the same way as java and you can use the <pre><code>HttPWebRequest</code> class to make the call to the web service

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514892

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i make a http get request with parameters in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514892/how-do-i-make-a-http-get-request-with-parameters-in-c-sharp)