# How to Retrieve Correct HTML From a Website

Tags: html, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I've tried this so far:

```
Dim wreq As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/goog/financials?query=income-statement&data=quarterly")
    wreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5"
    wreq.Method = "get"
    Dim prox As IWebProxy = wreq.Proxy
    prox.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    Dim document As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    Dim web As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb
    web.UseCookies = True
    web.PreRequest = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.PreRequestHandler(AddressOf onPreReq)
    wreq.CookieContainer = cookies
    Dim res As HttpWebResponse = wreq.GetResponse()
    document.Load(res.GetResponseStream, True)
    Debug.WriteLine(document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml)
```

But it returns the HTML for this web address: http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/goog/financials?query=income-statement

Instead of this one: http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/goog/financials?query=income-statement&data=quarterly

What am I doing wrong?

**Additional Info**

Here is `onPreReq`

```
Private Function onPreReq(req As HttpWebRequest)

    req.CookieContainer = cookies
    Return True

End Function
```

Comment: Just sounds like your `data` argument isn't getting passed. Maybe try it like this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17219511/1454048

Comment: @admdrew Sorry for being dense.  But I don't really understand how to apply that to my situation.

Comment: I haven't tried your code (I will later if I get time), but basically: the difference between your two web addresses is just the `&data=quarterly` part, which seems to be ignored, right? That's just an extra argument that's part of a standard HTTP `GET` request. Try using the method in the link I put above, see if that helps.

Comment: @admdrew I tired this `Dim url As String = "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/" & Ticker & "/financials?query=income-statement&data=quarterly"
          Dim wreq As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)` And I have the same problem.

Comment: Is there something in `onPreReq` that is changing the address. I dont have the HtmlAgilityPack so I commented out some code and added in some other and it looked correct.

Comment: @Steve I've edited my original post to add `onPreReq`.  I don't believe that it is changing the address.

Comment: If I click on this portion of code to follow the link `http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/goog/financials?query=income-statement&data=quarterly`  It actually takes me to this address `http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/v/financials` instead.

Comment: So if you click on the link you posted above, it brings you to another site? Strange. Note, I also did not use the cookies in my test because your code is incomplete. Perhaps the cookies are doing it to you, or the web site is redirecting you because you have been hitting it too much. I've seen that before. Unlikely because they just directed you to the wrong financials page. They would usually redirect you to some HTML page that says your doing something against thier policies.

Comment: @Steve I hope I'm not getting redirected due to hitting the site too much.  It is possible but I have tried to take precautions against hitting it too frequently.  How might the cookies be affecting me?  Do you have any ideas on what admdrew mentioned?  I'm still not quite getting what they are saying but it sounds like it could be helpful.

Comment: @Steve This code has worked in the past.  And I don't believe that I have done anything on my end to cause the problem.  I know website HTML can change but I'm not sure that is the case here.  I'm wondering if I'm getting redirected.

Comment: 1: I think admdrew was just pointing out the obvious between your 2 links. I dont believe you are doing it wrong. 2: I dont know what is in your cookies or how the website uses them. Try not passing them and see what happens. 3: All else fails, try your code on another computer on another public IP (ie, at a friends house) and see if it works. If so, the website is jacking you around because of the number of hits.

Comment: @Steve In regards to the intentional redirection, I can access the correct address from a browser on this computer.  I only get redirected from within my program.  Is this consistent with the website reacting to the number of hits?  In regards to the cookies, how do I run my code without passing the cookies?  I've tried and I can't get the code to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my variable `Ticker`.  It contains the ticker symbols that I use to create the web addresses.  I have been using all caps (ex. GOOG) up to this point.  I've changed all of my tickers to lower case (ex. goog) and that seems to have done the trick.