# WebClient post data issue

Tags: c#, webclient

I want to consume a REST API with webclient, here is my code and its throwing

> "validationObjective" not sent in the request .

But i added this validationobjective in my post

Can anyone help on this?

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string boundary = "------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", Convert.ToString("multipart/form-data; validationObjective=\"test\";boundary=") + boundary);
var fileData = webClient.Encoding.GetString(xmlFile);

var package = string.Format("--{0}" + Environment.NewLine + "Content-
    Disposition: form-data; name=\"ccdaFile\";validationObjective=\"test\";
    filename=\"{1}\"" + Environment.NewLine+ "Content-Type: {2}" 
    + Environment.NewLine + "{3}" + Environment.NewLine + "--{0}--" 
    + Environment.NewLine, boundary, "filename", "multipart/form-data", fileData);

var nfile = webClient.Encoding.GetBytes(package);
var resp = webClient.UploadData("url", "POST", nfile);
var bytesAsString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(resp);
```

Comment: This is completely off topic from your question, but please use StringBuilder for string concatenation rather.

Comment: This depends entirely on how that API is implemented. We can't say anything useful about this. My guess though is that it expects it as a form-data element, not in the Content-Type header.

Comment: Am I missing something here, what is a "validationObjective"? BTW I see no benefit in a StringBuilder in this scenario

Comment: I was trying to add a parameter called "validationobjective", even i added but API throwing that object not present in request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an HTTP get request with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514892/how-to-make-an-http-get-request-with-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. We need to send the parameter in querystring as like down

```
 webClient.QueryString.Add("referenceFileName", "sdfdsF");
 webClient.QueryString.Add("validationObjective", "sdfdsF");
```

This works for me!