# Adding parameters to GET API call

Tags: c#

Good evening!

This is my first time posting here and have looked throughout the web to try and discover how to do this. Essentially I am looking to add parameters within my GET API call.

This is my code so far

```
public string TestingRequest(string uri, string apiKey)
    {
        try
        {

            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {


                wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(apiKey, "MYSPORTSFEEDS");
                wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                wc.QueryString.Add("I don't know what goes here...");
                string HtmlResult = wc.DownloadString(uri);
                return HtmlResult;
            }
        }

        catch
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

I am wanting to return the 2017 season. The website I am using lists

season={season-identifier}
(optional) a specific season, identified by concatenating

(season start year) + "-" + 
(season end year) + "-" + 
either "regular" or "playoff", depending on the season's type

An example: "2017-regular"

EDIT: I added wc.QueryString.Add("season", "2017-regular"); per a comment below. I can't tell if it works or not. I set a break point on wc.DownloadString(uri); and when it hits that code, it bounces down to my catch block. I would think that would mean the program wasn't able to locate the uri

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514892/how-to-make-an-http-get-request-with-parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an HTTP get request with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514892/how-to-make-an-http-get-request-with-parameters)

Comment: There are four types of parameters: header parameters, path parameters, query string parameters, and request body parameters.  you can do some research now...

Comment: I looked at that link, I was just having trouble with the formatting of the parameter, would I set the QueryString.Add(season=2017-regular)?

Comment: Change your catch to catch (Exception ex) and then you can debug it and see exactly what the exception is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the the [add(String,String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.querystring.add?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_QueryString_Add_System_String_System_String_) method:

`wc.QueryString.Add("season","2017-regular");`

The first value is the parameter name, the second is the value of that parameter. 
Name would be Season, and the value would be the season that you're targeting.

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse! I keep getting a Null exception thrown...I wonder if I am just not referencing the JSON field correctly.