# How do I fire https url with headers in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I am using someone's API to get data.
The Api accepts a parameter and some headers.

Now in Postman I created a GET link and it fired perfectly.
In VB.NET I tried following code but I get error json response notifying that parameter missing.

Following is my VB.NET code

```
 Public Function MIGetGSTin(ByVal URL As String, ByVal accesstoken As String, ByVal clientID As String)
    Dim Requester As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)
    Requester.Method = "GET"
    Requester.Timeout = -1
    Requester.ContentType = "application/json"
    'Requester.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & accesstoken)
    'Requester.Headers.Add("client-id", clientID)
    Requester.Headers("Authorization") = "Bearer " & accesstoken
    Requester.Headers("client-id") = clientID

    Dim ResponseStreamReader As New StreamReader(Requester.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    Return ResponseStreamReader.ReadToEnd()

End Function
```

I also tried like during vb.net code execution I fetched the data, copied it and pasted in postman and it works there.

For a reference I post a pic of the manual to run the url which I was given by the API providers.

**NOTE :** Below image is just for reference. All credential data inside it is altered.

[image: SAMPLE OF API]

Also posting my postman setting

[image: POSTMAN DESCRIPTION]

NOTE : POSTMAN RESPONSE IS VALID. THIS POSTMAN SETTING IS WORKING. POSTMAN IS JUST FOR REFERENCE

I Don't know where I am wrong.
PLEASE NOTE IF ANYTHING IS NEEDED. 
THANK YOU

**UPDATE** : Also tried according to @Jimi said in the comments but not working. FOLLOWING is the new code below

```
Public Function MIGetGSTin(ByVal URL As String, ByVal accesstoken As String, ByVal clientID As String)
    Dim Requester As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(URL)
    Requester.Method = "GET"
    Requester.Timeout = -1
    Requester.ContentType = "application/json"
    Requester.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, $"Bearer {accesstoken}")
    Requester.Headers.Add("client-id", clientID)
    Requester.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache")
    'Requester.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & accesstoken)
    'Requester.Headers("Authorization") = "Bearer " & accesstoken
    'Requester.Headers("client-id") = clientID

    Using ResponseStreamReader As New StreamReader(Requester.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        Return ResponseStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using

    'Dim ResponseStreamReader As New StreamReader(Requester.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
End Function
```

Comment: Does the URL contain `?gstin=[some value]` query tuple? The correct form is `[HttpWebRequest].Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, $"Bearer {accesstoken}")`, the same for the other header. Add `Requester.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache")` Also change the WebRequest initialization in `Dim Requester = WebRequest.CreateHttp(URL)`

Comment: You should avoid this concatenation form: `Dim ResponseStreamReader As New StreamReader(Requester.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())`: both the HttpWebResponse and the Stream must be declared with `Using` statements

Comment: Ok I try and let you know.

Comment: @Jimi No `?gstin=[some value]` is single value and not a tuple or multiple values combined. (Searched query tuple on internet. rectify me if I am wrong.)
For Ex. `?gstin=24AAHDDA1231J` thats it.

Comment: @Jimi Not working I still get this error `{"error":true,"message":"paramter missing"}`. I wrote code according to what you said. Also Updating question again. Please check it.

Comment: In HTML, this: `?` is a query. What follows are query tuples, named like this because always come in pairs, as `https://SomeResource?param1=value1&param2=value2` -- All disposable objects need to be declared with `Using` statements, in your case it looks like this: `Using response = DirectCast(Requester.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse), responseStream = response.GetResponseStream(), reader = New StreamReader(responseStream) responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd() End Using`, a new line after each comma -- I don't see the URL you're passing. Keep in mind I cannot test it

Comment: @Jimi No its not query tuples. } 
Its just simple query. |  My URL is `https://commonapi.mastersindia.co/commonapis/searchgstin?gstin=24AIVPJ2870Q1ZF`

I give you credentials and you can check for sometime.
Is there any good way to contact.??

Comment: This: `?` is a Query and this: `gstin=24AIVPJ2870Q1ZF` is a Tuple (a Key / Value pair) -- You cannot contact me outside StackOverflow. You can post a link to the documentation though

Comment: Na na. Not outside. There is option to move this discussion to chat in stackoverflow. You give me time, I'll be there. I give you credentials to fire the query and lets test. Or if in comments you give me time, I'll be there. And yes this is single keyvalue pair as you said and won't be any other keyvalue pair after this separating by & or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out after a lot of hard work and searching.
I did it with a webclient.

Following is the Link I got help from : [How to make an HTTP get request with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514892/how-to-make-an-http-get-request-with-parameters)

Below is my code.

```
Public Function GetAPIData(ByVal URL As String, ByVal accesstoken As String, ByVal clientID As String)
    Dim result As String = ""
    Using wc As New WebClient
        wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json")
        wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, $"Bearer {accesstoken}")
        wc.Headers.Add("client_id", clientID)
        result = wc.DownloadString(URL)
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```

And this work like charm. 
I hope this helps anyone. 
Thank You. _/\_